# C++ Temperature Conversion

Tags: c++

I know this is very simple.  But I am new to C++.
I need to write a program that converts Centigrade temperatures to Fahrenheit and displays it. The formula provided by my professor is: Fahrenheit = (5/9) * Centigrade + 32.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

float ctemp;

cout << "What is the temperature out in Centigrade? ";
cin >> ctemp;

float ftemp = (5/9) * ctemp + 32;

cout << "That is " << ftemp << " in Fahrenheit" << endl;

cin.get();
cin.get();
return 0;
}
```

No matter what temperature i enter for cin ctemp, i get 32.  Something is wrong with my order of operations?  Any help appreciated.  I know this most likely simple, so please dont bag on this question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
float ftemp = (5/9) * ctemp + 32;
```

This line contains a minor bug. You should cast the ints to floats since that is the type you want to get. Something like this should do the trick:

```
float ftemp = (5.0f/9.0f) * ctemp + 32.0f;
```

Comment: Thank you much.  And this makes sense for my own future reference, i will not run into this mistake again.  Much appreciated.

Comment: No problem, I often make that mistake myself!

Comment: Can i ask what the f is for?

Comment: @AdamJosephLooze The type of `5.0` is `double`, while the type of `5.0f` is `float`. I suggest you using `double` in the whole program instead.

Answer (score -1):

Added to Drew Dormann's answer: it's `(9.0f/5.0f)` for the proper conversion from `C` to `F`.